# What is the text of Kiddush Levana (?) during a blue moon?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Kiddush Levana is the sanctification of the "white one", i.e. the moon. Now of course, the moon is usually white, but every so often (7 times in 19 years, as a matter of fact) we end up with a blue moon.

The text, indeed the very name of Kiddush Levana makes reference to the moon's normal white color. What should be said when it is blue?

Sources please.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Curious. How do you know that the blue moon occurs 7 times in 19 years?

Comment: @DanF https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_moon#Definition Which makes sense, as it's the same cycle our leap year is on (adding an extra month to match the lunar calendar with the solar one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full p'sak on this issue is contained within the [popular ancient zemer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Moon_(1934_song)):

> Blue moon,|I saw you standing alone|without a dream in my heart|without a love of my own.

- If one is standing alone, one cannot properly fulfill the portion of the sanctification that requires saying and responding to "Shalom Aleichem." Nor can one conclude with the Kaddish.
- One cannot mention the "dream" of fulfillment during yemos moshiach, which precludes the brachah and the Tana Divei Rabbi Yishmael.
- Nor can one recite any quotes from Shir Hashirim (a love of my own).

The next verses of the zemer deal with the remaining portions of Kiddush Levana, but the author will not trouble the reader by belaboring the point. Ultimately, one may not, in fact, make a declaration over a blue moon, as each portion of the tefilla is individually deemed by Chazal as inappropriate to recite under these circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

When the moon is blue, we say basically the same *kidush l'vana*, but try to squeeze in some mention of its blue status:

- We say "הַלְלוּהוּ כָּל כּוֹכְבֵי אוֹר" (in the introductory psalm) with more *kavana*.
- We change "בָּרוּךְ יוֹצְרֵךְ" (and the others) to "בָּרוּךְ יוֹצְרֵכֶם" (et al.), and have in mind that it applies to the stars also. Likewise, we change "כְּשֵׁם שֶׁאֲנִי רוֹקֵד כְּנֶגְדֵּךְ וְאֵינִי יָכוֹל לִנְגּוֹעַ בָּךְ" to "כְּשֵׁם שֶׁאֲנִי רוֹקֵד כְּנֶגְדְּכֶם וְאֵינִי יָכוֹל לִנְגּוֹעַ בָּכֶם".
- Finally, we change "לַעֲמוּסֵי בָטֶן שֶׁהֵם עֲתִידִים לְהִתְחַדֵּשׁ כְּמוֹתָהּ" (in the actual blessing) to "לַעֲמוּסֵי בָטֶן שֶׁהֵם עֲתִידִים לֹא לְהִסָּפֵר כְּכוֹכְבֵי הַשָּׁמַיִם **וְכַחוֹל**".

Comment: I don't get why we're emphasizing the stars. Care to expand on that?

Comment: @Scimonster, just to get to the punch line.

Answer (score 1):

You would change absolutely nothing when the moon is blue. If the moon is blue, it means it is sad, so something is definitely wrong with it. So we pray to G-d in the opening bracha that the moon should not be sad or blue, as it says:

> שָֹשִֹים וּשְֹמֵחִים לַעֲשֹוֹת רְצוֹן קוֹנָם
>
> They are joyful and happy to perform the will of their possessor.

Comment: Who are "they" in your interpretation?

Comment: Ah ... very astute question! Look at the phrasing at the beginning of the bracha. It says, וּבְרוּחַ פִּיו כָּל צְבָאָם . It talks about the galaxies and their "hosts". It seems that the "hosts" (in plural) is a reference to the sun and moon.

Answer (score 1):

There is a machlokess ha'poskim concerning this shaalah.

Tosafos say you can only make kiddush levana on a blue moon in Kentucky, as the passuk says 'blue moon over Kentucky'.

The tashbatz on the other hand says that a blue moon is caused by volcanic dust in the atmosphere that filters out the longer red wavelengths. According to this the beracha can be made only by Vulcans, but the location is unimportant.

The Chofetz Chaim is machmir for both deos which explains why Vulcan's never talk lashon hara.